# Default i2c not working in compute module

Tags: raspbian, i2c, compute-module-3

I am trying to communicate with the two i2c devices using the gpio pins 0 and 1 for the first device and 1 and 2 for the second device.

I can communicate to the i2c device using the gpio pins 0 and 1 but unable to communicate using the gpio pins 2 and 3.

I searched and tried several options but still no luck

Following is my observations

**OS version and i2c details**
[image]

**I2C Configuration**

[image]
[image]

**I2C details before connecting devices to the pin 2 and 3**
[image]

**After connecting the i2c device**
[image]

I noticed the gpio 2 level number is zero  before connecting the device and changed when I connected the device  in raspi-gpio get output

Still, I don't know why it's not communicating? Anyone who understands the issue please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Need clear photos showing the connections.

Comment: My connections are correct..., I tried swapping the connections from 0,1 to 2,3 but the same result

Comment: I strongly doubt I have changed the pin configuration somewhere else other than config.txt,  But I am not remembering that. Maybe the default pulldown settings or alternate functionality something like that. 

I have checked this in /sys/class/gpio/ It seems not used as a GPIO pin.   What are the other settings files that I can check this?

Comment: Look level showing 0 in gpio pin 2

Comment: Your connections are not correct.  If they were you would not be getting the i2cdetect results you are.

Comment: I tried with a new Rpi image and it's working correctly... But I need the existing RPi image because it is already configured with other software. It's difficult to create a new Rpi image... My USB Wifi dongle is not working with the new Rpi image

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.